# Apache Airflow:Create reusable custom TaskGroup

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am trying to create a custom TaskGroup class to replace existing subdags in our airflow pipelines.

My concern is to pass the dag object instead of using context manager. I used this [tutorial](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/task-groups#custom-task-group-classes) to create custom class.

Let's have a look at my custom TaskGroup code:

```
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from airflow.decorators import task

class TestTaskGroup(TaskGroup):
    def __init__(self, dag,  group_id="TestTaskGroup", *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(dag=dag,group_id=group_id, *args, **kwargs)
        self.dag = dag

        @task(task_group=self)
        def emptyTask():            
            EmptyOperator(task_id="emptytask", dag=self.dag)
            

        @task(task_group=self)
        def pythonTask():            
            PythonOperator(task_id="pythontask", dag=self.dag, python_callable=lambda:print("Hello World"))

        emptyTask() >> pythonTask()
```

In testdag.py :

```
from taskgroups.testtaskgroup import TestTaskGroup
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id="testdag",
    start_date = datetime(2024,2,26),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    default_args={
        "owner":"hemant.sah",
    }
) 

sometask = EmptyOperator(task_id="sometask", dag=dag)
grouptask = TestTaskGroup(dag=dag)

sometask >>grouptask
```

Above code gives me error:

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Tried to create relationships between tasks that don't have DAGs yet. Set the DAG for at least one task and try again: [<Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): TestTaskGroup.emptyTask>, <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): TestTaskGroup.pythonTask>]
```

**What I tried:**

I tried bringing TestTaskGroup inside context manager, this way it works but I want to understand why it's not working when I pass a dag object in `TestTaskGroup(dag=dag)`

```
with DAG() as dag:
    sometask = EmptyOperator(task_id="sometask")
    grouptask = TestTaskGroup() # in this way I am not passing dag object and it works
    sometask >> grouptask
```

I could not find a way where I can pass dag object without creating context manager.
Preferring this approach because we have many dags and by following this approach can reduce code changes.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your TaskGroup is badly indented. You should define them in the class and not in the constructor (that would be my guess)

Comment: I followed this link: https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/task-groups#custom-task-group-classes. But I will give a try and make tasks outside the constructor.

Comment: Update: taking tasks outside constructor throws error as it uses self to register inside a taskgroup

Comment: nonetheless it's indented incorrectly. The tasks should not be inside the init function

Comment: the guess is wrong. it does not work to be defined at the class level, only if defined in the init part.

Comment: @Tata I added my tasks in init and it works that way. I wanted dag object to be passed in  custom class specifically and inside init I used with context to achieve what I wanted. Got boiler code from astronomer docs. I still  want someone to write proper documentation in airflow for custom taskgroup classes. I really could not found anywhere.